# Restore rEfind on macbook dual-boot after install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, refind

I tried to set up dual-booting on my macbook mostly following [these instructions](https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733).

Everything seemed fine, up to the very last step; when I rebooted the system (even if I held command-R) I didn't get any rEFInd boot menu or recovery mode, it just booted to Ubuntu with no way of recovering OSX.

The solution: install refind again.

```
sudo apt install refind
```

It will insist on installation to the right partition for EFI. Once it's done, just reboot (this made me nervous, but it worked out ok). Next boot you'll see the OSX and ubuntu options in the refind menu.